# График искаженной линии

Tags: python

Как построить график из таких данных:
`[0,0,1,1,0,0,2,0,1,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0]`
Такого вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где от 1 до 2х рисуется линия. Некоторые аспекты - рисуем по последней единице или двойке. Если значение например 0,1,1 - то берется последнее значение для нижней точки, а если ,0,1,0,0,1,0, то для низа также берется последнее значение 1.

Comment: Логика рисования непонятная. А нарисовать можно, например, через PIL или PyQt5

Comment: Объясните в терминах координат. Какие будут координаты `(x,y)`, по которым строится график? Вот это вот про единицы, двойки и нижнюю точку - так ничего непонятно. Покажите в координатах - по каким точкам должны рисоваться линии, по каким конкретным координатам.

Comment: Здесь 25 значений среди которых нули. x = 25 значений. А рисоватся в y будут линии от 2 до 1, от 1 до 2 и т.д. Но бывают когда подряд идут два или три значения одинаковых и стоит вопрос какие выбрать - вот тут выбираем всегда последнее для построения.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Из вашего описания не просто понять, как же именно требуется изобразить ломанную. Надеюсь я угадал.

```
data = [0,0,1,1,0,0,2,0,1,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0]
#             ^     ^   ^   ^           ^     ^     ^
# если я правильно понял, то надо найти выше отмеченные 
# элементы списка и построить график
# где X = индекс элемента в списке
# а Y = значение самого элемента

points = [[0, 1]]    # координаты [X,Y] первой точки
for i, value in enumerate(data):
    if value == points[-1][1]:
        # если значение то же, что и Y последней точки,
        # то просто обновляем ей координату X
        points[-1][0] = i
    elif value:
        # для ненулевого значения, которое не совпало 
        # с Y последней точки, создаём новую точку
        points.append([i, value])

print(points)

# выводим график
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xx, yy = zip(*points)
plt.plot(xx, yy, "-ok")
plt.xticks(range(len(data)))
plt.yticks([1, 2])
plt.show()
```

Найденные точки:

```
[[3, 1], [6, 2], [8, 1], [10, 2], [16, 1], [19, 2], [22, 1]]
```

[image: График]

Comment: большое спасибо, все именно так